# Compass heading bad calibration

Tags: iphone, mapkit, heading

I have a compass app and the problem is that it's take some turnes to get calibrated.
The second the app is loaded it shows the wrong heading and only after some left and right turnes it gives the right heading.
I have the "locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration" function returns "YES" but it never ask to calibrate...
Maybe I miss here some technique?

Thanks

Comment: Only people who own a real compass know that ;-) I have the same problem, I want to force the display to compe up evrytime when the vie wappears. better some turns than to walk 45° degrees in the wrong direction. Have you found a solution?